# Javascript and bing maps, display the map of an address (not using latitude/longitude)

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I would like to display a bing map using an address, and not using latitude/longitude.

Is it possible?

How? Is there a simple API or plugin for doing so?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Bing Maps Geocoding API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161074.aspx). This one allows you to give an address to draw on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, what you need is geocoding. Geocoding is the process to convert address into coordinates. Once you get coordinates you can use that in map.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx

Comment: The way you do is create geocode() function, send address as parameter. You will receive a JSON file from bing map webservice. You need to parse that file to get latitude and longitude.

Comment: There is no a simple way ? Just display the map from an adress ( in the latest v7 api). Is there an exemple, because i'm a noob in javascript :s Thanks :)

Comment: Map will only take points as input. Address must be translated into points to points. That is a standard way to do it. The reason is that same address may return several points. You need to decide which point you want to use. Google map API is also same. Besides how much more simple can it get?

Comment: Yes i understand, but i would like an exemple if possible

Comment: Did you check this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161074.aspx This has entire example.

Comment: Yes, i checked this and there is at end a entire exemple. Nevertheless, if i paste it in a new html doc, no map appear :(